# How to calculate start and end dates of blocks of cells in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following table in Excel 2013:

[image: Excel table]

The column Dates consists of consequent 2-weeks intervals. Other columns have coloured cells that indicate when the event lasts for different Addresses. For example, for Address 2 the event lasts from 13.01.2020 till 09.02.2020. I need to transform this table into the table with columns:

`Start Date | Finish date | Address`

For each Address there can be several time intervals during which the event lasts, so there can be several rows for each Address.

I can easily separate start and finish date of each 2-weeks interval with Text to Columns and I can fill coloured blocks with numbers for easier manipulation with cells. But I have no idea how to count the start date and the length of blocks in order to count the end date of each block. I'm sure it can be done with some VBA coding but it isn't my strongest side. Is there a way to do it with built-in Excel functionality? The original table consists of about 50 addresses and 30 2-weeks intervals.

Thank you!

Comment: Just parsing out the dates from that combined string of non-standard date formats would be tricky enough with worksheet formulas. Detecting colored cells is a whole other nest of snakes. I'd write a VBA user defined function that retrieves either the start or finish date from your original table. Alternately, a VBA sub procedure could build the new table on the fly but it wouldn't be auto-calculated.